# Git not recognizing online repo

Tags: git, repository

I need to get a driver from ENAC, which posts the driver online [here](http://lii-enac.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi).  The trouble is, git does not see it as a repo.

```
git clone http://lii-enac.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=linux-input/hid-multitouch.git;a=tree;f=drivers;h=4a0269c4d150aa46c245b05a3ceca95eb373980c;hb=HEAD
Cloning into 'hid-multitouch'...
fatal: repository 'http://lii-enac.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=linux-input/hid-multitouch.git/' not found
```

How do I use git to clone the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
git clone git://git.lii-enac.fr/linux-input/hid-multitouch
```

Found a similar link on this page: http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-ubuntu-howto.html

The link you've tried is just for the web view of the repo.